# TinyMCE Paths, How to specify where to load things like editor_plugin.js

Tags: jquery, tinymce, google-closure

I installed TinyMCE, everything was working great. I then used Google Closure to package my site's JavaScript along with TinyMCE_src

The problem I'm having is that TinyMCE is now making calls to:

```
plugins/paste/editor_plugin.js
themes/advanced/editor_template.js
langs/en.js
```

And that paths that are being used are invalid, they are 404'ing

How can I tell TinyMCE where to go to get these files?

I tried:

```
relative_urls : false,
document_base_url : "http://www.site.com/path1/",
```

But they have no effect on the files above.

Advise? Thanks

Comment: in my case, I didn't use anything like "Google Closure". Just wanted to load TinyMCEs dynamically. I'm using `jquery.tinymce.js`. When I load the TinyMCE, Firebug gives errors, where it is obvious that JQuery is trying to load smth like `/_cms/products//langs/en.js` instead of `/tinymce/langs/en.js`

Comment: I encountered the same problem when bundeling my javascript files. WHen looking at the TinyMce source it seens it has a few different ways to find the base adress to load its modules. One of them is to look in hte dom for the adress that is used to include tiny_mce.js. This obviosly fails when including the file in a bundle. I fixed the problem by adding tinyMCE.baseURL before my tinyMCE.init.

Answer (score 103):

I had the same issue, and it could have been solved easily if we were able to specify the **base url** using the **document_base_url**.

Alternatively, I was able to specify the base url before initializing tinymce.

```
tinyMCE.baseURL = "URL_TO/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/";// trailing slash important

tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple"
});
```

TinyMCE is working fine now.

Comment: Tested in latest 4.0b1 version - working! Also, I had to add tinyMCE.suffix = '.min';

Comment: In version 4.0.16 don't add a trailing slash.

Comment: Could not find this documented anywhere.  Am I missing something or did the only way to learn this involve digging through source code?

Comment: Still working as of `4.6.6`. Just set `tinymce.baseURL = '/path/to/tinymce';` before `tinymce.init({...});` http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:property.tinymce.EditorManager.baseURL.static

Comment: Still working in `4.9.1` - I had to use both `tinymce.baseURL = "/path/to/tinymce";` and `tinyMCE.suffix = '.min';` to make it work

Comment: This is still a valid answer for version 5.6

Comment: With `6.0.0` the key has changed to `base_url: '/dist/tinymce'`.

Comment: @TobiG. In 6.1.0 it is baseURL (again?)

Answer (score 9):

You can override the base url for tinyMCE by placing the following code before initializing tinyMCE.

```
var tinyMCEPreInit = {
    suffix: '',
    base: '/tinymce/',
    query: ''
};
```

This is usefull if you already loaded tinyMCE from a merged source and the base path isn't correctly found.

Comment: `var tinyMCEPreInit` may have to be `window.tinyMCEPreInit`

Answer (score 9):

According this: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_url

```
tinymce.init({
   ...
   theme_url: (document.location.pathname + '/js/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js').replace("\/\/", "\/"),
   skin_url:  (document.location.pathname + '/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/').replace("\/\/", "\/"),
   ...
```

But, need to be carefull with paths. With help `document.location.pathname` I've got project root directory. Replace function need for replacing double slash with single slash, because different server can return "...//server/site" OR "...//server/site/" and it can be:
"...//server/site/js..." OR "...//server/site//js...".

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. `document_base_url` and `relative_urls` seemed to do nothing.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the TinyMCE jQuery plugin, you can load everything from a remote location, just add the `script_url` parameter into your init code. It will load everything from there, including any scripts/images/etc.

```
$('textarea').tinymce({
    script_url: 'http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
});
```

Check out this fiddle, it's including the whole thing remotely from the TinyMCE website: http://jsfiddle.net/xgPzS/22/

Comment: doesn't help :( Can't figure out what's the reason, but JQuery doesn't call to valid URL. Instead of giving 404 I print the requested URL (`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) and Firebug shows the following error: `invalid regular expression flag p  /_cms/products//themes/simple/editor_template.js` (because of the `/` JQuery thinks it's a regexp :) )

Comment: It's not JS, it's the reply from server :) The server just prints the URL that JQuery is trying to reach! JQuery "waits for" JS code, but the JS does not exist in the URL it's requesting

Comment: @Hrant Khachatrian: You php should look something like this: `$('textarea').tinymce({ script_url: '<?php echo $whatever_variable_with_your_script_path; ?>subdirectory/whatever.js' });` If you do that, the generated HTML that's sent to your browser will contain the correct path to the script. Note the string wrapping quotes before and after the php tag.

Comment: the path is correct for sure. I've also tried your suggestion (script_url points to tinymce.moxiecode.com), but the error remains. In fact it seems I've found the reason of this problem... After double-checking I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

As per TinyMCE 4.x documentation you can specify the document base url during init.

```
tinymce.init({
        document_base_url: "http://www.example.com/path1/"
});
```

if you are using CodeIgniter, simply use `base_url()`

```
tinymce.init({
        document_base_url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>"
});
```

Remember: `relative_url` must be **true** in order to work it perfectly otherwise you will get absolute URLS.

For more details:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:document_base_url

Answer (score 2):

Bundle everything using grunt (instructions on [github](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce#build-tasks)) then you will just have to configure from where to load all the css using the option `skin_url`

```js
tinymce.init({skin_url: window.location.origin + '/css/tinymce'})
```